# Drupal Custom Menu Styling

Tags: css, drupal

i created a custom menu called "top-navigation". Now I'd like to style it with css.
Any idea how that works?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you're not using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for Firefox, you need to be.

That said, have you already added the menu to your site somewhere? If not, go to /admin/build/block and put the menu's block in a block region.

Once that's done, just use Firebug (or you can just view source) to figure out the ID or class of the menu, and then use that in your CSS.